# Python import import libraries in same script

Tags: python, matplotlib

Let's say I have a library of plotting functions, all of which require importing matplotlib among a few other libraries. It would be cumbersome to do something like:

```
def plot1(a,b,c,d):
    import matplotlib
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    ...
    ...

def plot2(a,b,c,d):
    import matplotlib
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    ...
    ...
```

Is there a way to be able to define the import matplotlib (and others) as a function, and simply import *that*? For example:

```
script1.py

def load_matplotlib_funcs():
    import matplotlib
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    ...
    ...



def plot1(a,b,c,d):
    import load_matplotlib_funcs
    ...
```

Doing this does not seem to produce the desired results of utilizing matplotlib as.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to just put the imports at the top of your file?

Comment: Is there something wrong with just putting `import matplotlib
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` at the top of the file?

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would just put the imports at the top of your file and all functions have access to them:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot1(a,b,c,d):
    ...

def plot2(a,v,c,d):
    ...
```

There are only two reasons that I can think of that you would want to import modules on the flow:

- circular imports if used globally
- on-demand imports in case if they are slow to load (e.g. tensorflow) and there are not needed for *every* run of your program.

You can of course write an extra file that handles these imports for you

```
# optional.py with on-demand imports
# matplotlib imports are fast, no need to outsource them!
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# slow imports which are not needed for every program run could be outsourced
import torch
import sklearn
import tensorflow
# ...
```

```
# your normal file

def myfunc():
   from optional import * 
   t = torch.Tensor()

# ... rest of the code that does not need the torch module
```

---

**In general there is no reason to do on-demand imports. You can save some import time, but your code will become more error prone** (e.g. missing packages detected much later)

Using the stared import * will also make it harder for IDEs to check the correctness of your code (and for yourself).

---

Alternatively to stay close to your original idea you can of course do it, but as the variables of the modules are locally bound you need to carry them over. For multiple functions it will quickly start to get messy:

```
def my_imports():
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   import numpy as np
   return np, plt

def plot():
   np, plt = my_imports()
```